# Unable to open Ambari login page with Hadoop (http://127.0.0.1:8080/)

Tags: hadoop, browser, ambari

I have opened the virtual box, put in the password, and typed in ifconfig to find out the host address, which is http://127.0.0.1:8080/. However, I still cannot open the Ambari login page. I have tried multiple browsers, including IE, Chrome and firefox. None of them worked.

Basically the browser gives me the following message:

```
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:8080 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Are you using a browser on the vm? Or are you using the browser on the host machine? If you are using the browser on your host machine the 127.0.0.1 address isn't going to work. What is the output of ifconfig?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had a conflict with my local IIS that was hosting a local website on port 8080.

I solved the problem by changing the ambari port to 8082.

This is how I did it.
1) I first checked to see if port 8082 was in use using netstat, you could also check if 8080 is in use to confirm you have the same problem.

2) Fireup the hadoop VM and login.

3) Follow the link below, this will show you how to change the ambari port
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.1.0/bk_ambari_reference_guide/content/_optional_changing_the_default_ambari_server_port.html

4) Restart ambari
https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.0/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap2-3.html

5) Re-configure port forwarding on your VirtualBox. There is a section in the following blog.
http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I am using virtual box, i just started the "Hortonworks Sandbox" from Virtualbox and my ambari worked.
http://127.0.0.1:8080